# is there a way to split this sum into 2 parts

Tags: functions

I'm working on a shader and have the following formula: 
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{z-d}}$$
now I'm taking the sum over both z and d which is computationally not very deficient 
$$\text{so  }r=\Sigma\Sigma \frac{1}{1+e^{z-d}}$$
Now if I can somehow split this into 2 parts containing z and d then this could be done very efficiently. Is there a way to split this into $f(z)+g(n)$ somehow? Or is there a theory that says this cannot be done?

I have tried to take the ln of the whole thing (calculate $ln(r)$) and look at the series expansion but that didn't work.

Comment: How do $z$ and $d$ vary ?

Comment: Both are integers over which we take the sum from 1 to a given number.

Comment: You should have said it in the first place. Use the recurrence $e^{k+1}=e\cdot e^k$ to avoid exponentials.

Comment: How large is the "given number" ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have finite lists $z_1,\dots,z_k$ and $d_1,\dots,d_l$ you could first calculate the vectors
\begin{align*}
v_z &= (e^{z_1},\dots,e^{z_k}), \\
v_d &= (e^{-d_1},\dots,e^{-d_l}),
\end{align*}
then obtain the $k\times l$ matrix
$$
v_z^T v_d =
\pmatrix{
e^{z_1-d_1} & \cdots & e^{z_1-d_l} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
e^{z_k-d_l} & \cdots & e^{z_k-d_l}
}.
$$
Now you can add the all-one matrix, take the reciprocal of all entries and sum over all entries.

This way, you have to calculate only $l+k$ instead of $l\cdot k$ exponentials for the naive approach.

Splitting the sum into $f(v_z) + g(v_d)$ doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Anyway, the global complexity remains $O(l\cdot k)$.

Comment: This solution may not be practical since the problem likely involves computer floating point numbers that are not quantized on a lattice of reasonable spacing (vs the natural quantizing of ieee floats that includes just way too many values to make the above practical for most devices/PCs). However, if the resolution of the graphics (shader?) can in fact be reduced, then pre-calculating all the possible combinations (the matrix above) is a great improvement to the real-time/naive approach. You take O(l*k) likely at most once in the program's life and then do O(l+k) per sub-second frame.

Comment: Tried to edit the earlier comment but ran out of time. Anyway, I think this solution just says to pre-compute values once and then do table lookup. That reduced the time of computing a complex function, but you still have O(l*k) additions. This can be a great improvement if the problem accepts a significant reduced space (vs generic z and d). If you can't reduce the size of the discrete set of points, then the memory shuffling cost can far exceed the computation of the functions within the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

If $z-d$ is always large, you can approximate as
$$\sum\sum\frac1{1+e^{z-d}}\approx\sum\sum e^de^{-z}=\left(\sum e^d\right)\left(\sum e^{-z}\right).$$

If $z-d$ is always small, you can use the Taylor development and

$$\sum\sum\frac1{1+e^{z-d}}\approx\sum\sum\left(1-e^ze^{-d}+e^{2z}e^{-2d}\cdots\right)=\\\left(\sum 1\right)\left(\sum1\right)-\left(\sum e^z\right)\left(\sum e^{-d}\right)+\left(\sum e^{2z}\right)\left(\sum e^{-2d}\right)\cdots$$

If $z$ or $d$ follow an arithmetic progression, the sums are immediate.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{z-d}}+\frac{1}{1+e^{d-z}}=1$$
so if $d$ takes the same values that $z$ does, that fact could speed  up the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

For the variables $z$ and $d$ on an integer lattice $[1,n]\times[1,m]$, you can speed up the computation.

Indeed, consider all couples $(z,d)$ such that $z-d=k$ (a straight line). For all these couples, the summand has the same value, $\dfrac1{1+e^k}$.

If you work by increasing values of $k$, there are three regimes. First the number of admissible couples will go increasing, from $1$ to $\min(m,n)$, then it will stay constant, then decrease back to $1$ (imagine the intersection of a moving oblique line with a rectangle).

To efficiently compute the sum, multiply every term by its number of occurrences. The terms themselves can be computed incrementally, without needing to use the exponential function.

The total workload is $O(n+m)$ and no more $O(n\cdot m)$.

---

If you go to large values of $k$ (say $|k|>10$), most of the terms can be regrouped and computed with approximation formulas. For a given error tolerance, I guess that the whole computation can be done in constant time $O(1)$.

---

Even better, if you tabulate $\sum_0^k\dfrac1{1+e^i}$ and $\sum_0^k\dfrac i{1+e^i}$ (also for negative $k$), you can perform the exact computation in constant time.

Comment: In the general case, there need not be more than 1 couple corresponding to the same k (even for a certain error tolerance). In this case the final result is O(l*k).

Comment: @Jose_X: we are not in the general case, we are on a digital rectangle (dense integer lattice). There is an exact $O(1)$ solution, using two precomputed $1D$ tables.

Comment: You certainly qualified your solution, but I was pointing out that I don't think the question (at the time I read it at least) is limited to integer values of z and d (although maybe the author intended to limit to integers).

Comment: I think I missed those comments, not sure why. On this browser, I almost can't make out the gray dividing line and perhaps thought it was .. well.. sorry about that.